# openpyxl chart label overlapping with data

Tags: python, openpyxl

[image]

As picture shown above, is there any attribute in `openpyxl` that could make the labels of data not overlap with the negative columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a specification for the `x_axis tick label position`:

```py
chart.x_axis.tickLblPos = "low" #this is actually at the top of the graph
```